# Organization Chart Wizard from Excel to Visio is too vertical

Tags: microsoft-visio-2013

I imported a excel file to visio through org chart wizard. It came out as expected EXCEPT for it was too vertical. It came out like this:

[image: initial output by auto import]

I need it like this:
[image: Image 2]

I acomplished this by manually dragging things, is it possible to make it do belts on every row automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open a organization chart in Visio 2013 there is a tab called `ORG CHART`. Click on it and go to layout and select the first one (center). That did the trick for me when I tried to replicate your problem. If it is not the first one than try them all out. Also don't forget that you can select only a part of your visio diagram and change the layout.

Also there is the Tab Design → Re-Layout Page. If the above did not help try the different options here.

[image]